# Need help extracting Google Cartoon Dataset on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am looking to work on Google Cartoon dataset available at https://google.github.io/cartoonset/download.html. I would be using Googel Colab to work on classification tasks, but that is later. Right now the challenge is 1. how to I get data to Colab directly or to google drive, I did use -

```
! wget --no-check-certificate \
    https://storage.cloud.google.com/cartoonset_public_files/cartoonset100k.tgz
```

This only gets me a small 60kb file in colab, and then second part is how do I extract the subfolders directly in colab temp files . I did try

```
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive("cartoonset10k.tgz", "/tmp/")

with tarfile.open('cartoonset10k.tgz', 'r:gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall()
```

error - ReadError: not a gzip file

```
!tar -xzf cartoonset10k.tgz -C ~/tmp/
```

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I can download the data to system and unzip it that works, but the challenge is to upload it again to colab, that takes ages on internet I have.

Answer (score 1):

Google requires you to login before downloading through http. The 60k file is actually an HTML page asking you to login, not the data itself.

It's difficult to login with wget or curl or selenium.

Luckily, you can use `gsutil` for direct download without authentication.

```
!gsutil cp gs://cartoonset_public_files/cartoonset100k.tgz .
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your command and i am getting error "CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command."

Comment: You forgot the dot at the end.